# Why is ContextRefreshEvent in Spring Boot not firing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

I'm trying to seed a database on Spring Boot web application startup.  I followed the example I found here: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-a-database-seeder-in-spring-boot where the seeder runs when the ContextRefreshEvent fires.

Here is my code fragment which is supposed to handle the ContextRefreshedEvent:

```
@EventListener
public void seed(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    System.out.println("DatabaseSeeder.seed: ContextRefreshedEvent fired, beginning to seed database...");
    AddressSeeder addressSeeder = new AddressSeeder();
    addressSeeder.seed();
```

But its not working for me.  My database is not being seeded and the output message in the same area is not getting hit.  At least it doesn't show up in the console window where, as I understand, they are supposed to be routed by default in Spring.

Here is a screenshot how I have the code organized:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I should add that I am also using flyway for version control of the mysql schema.  It successfully created all the tables in the first run.  It is also possible to do the seeding in flyway but I think it would mean having to do it in SQL, rather than using java and JSON, like I'm trying to do now.

Comment: This method has to be inside a component (or at least a bean registered through `@Bean` else it won't get registered). That being said, generally to receive events from the spring container you need an `ApplicationListener` as the `@EventListener` annotations are processed later on in the container lifecycle.